# react-native fetch join all set-cookie

Tags: react-native, cookies, fetch

I am trying to parse cookies from fetch, but what I have:
in response I have not `response.cookie = [...]` but `response.cookie.map = [...]`
Aaaand in this array I receive only 1 string, where all cookie joined with ',', for example

> GV_publickey=7ghbnTEUghv66fEK_c1oRi098pNPaGSD; Path=/,
>   csrftoken=qq49ms8fEOUUKn0WfdXs0O4rVf75qXIAP2B38n0Afo4g6LVuzzYqBvT5xItAfk9V;
>   expires=Thu, 06-Jun-2019 18:08:55 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/

It is string with 2 cookies GV_publickey and csrftoken. 
How I can parse it? Or some parameter exists to split it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been an annoyance in react native for a while. I just recently merged a PR into `set-cookie-parser` to handle this, please try it out and let me know if it works for you:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/set-cookie-parser#usage-in-react-native